# How to assign uploaded image to specific DocumentID?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-storage

I have a simple form with textfields and image picker, user can upload it to Firebase.

How to `let @DocumentID = ...` in **Storage** section?
**Purpose:** I need the image to be saved as a link in one document. At the moment the image is saved only in **Storage**. How to do it correctly?

All attempts led me to the fact that `pic` is created as a separate document in the database, and not inside same document.

[image]

Button: **Done** -[AddItemView]

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = NewItemView()

func handleDoneTapped() {
    self.viewModel.handleDoneTapped()
    self.uploadImage()
    self.dismiss()
}
```

**Storage** section -[AddItemView]

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = NewItemView()

func uploadImage() {
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let picData: Data  = pickedImages[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
//        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let path = "itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
    let ref = storage.child(path)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
    let uploadTask = ref.putData(picData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (storageMetaData, error) in
            
        if error != nil {
                
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return

        }
    })        
}
```

All `var`s -[SingleItem]

```
struct SingleItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?   // How I can use it in Storage section?
    var title : String
    var author : String
    var description : String
    @ServerTimestamp var createdTime: Timestamp?
    var userId : String?
    var pic : String
}
  
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case author
    case description = ""
    case pic
}
```

**Firestore** -[NewItemView]

```
class NewItemView: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - Public properties
  
    @Published var singleitem: SingleItem
    @Published var modified = false
  
    // MARK: - Internal properties
  
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
    // MARK: - Constructors
  
    init(singleitem: SingleItem = SingleItem(title: "", author: "", description: "", pic: "")) {
        self.singleitem = singleitem
    
        self.$singleitem
            .dropFirst()
            .sink { [weak self] singleitem in
                self?.modified = true
            }
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
  
    // MARK: - Firestore
  
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
    private func addItem(_ singleitem: SingleItem) {
        do {
            var addedItem = singleitem
            addedItem.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            _ = try db.collection("items").addDocument(from: addedItem)
        
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }      
      
    }

    private func updateItem(_ singleitem: SingleItem) {
        if let documentID = singleitem.id {
            do {
                try db.collection("items").document(documentID).setData(from: singleitem)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateOrAddItem() {
        if singleitem.id != nil {
            self.updateItem(self.singleitem)
        }
        else {
            addItem(singleitem)
        }
    }

    func handleDoneTapped() {     // And this func I call in Done button
        self.updateOrAddItem()
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create your `path`, assign it to a `String` property on your model in Firestore -- no need to use `@DocumentID` for it

Comment: @jnpdx thank thanks for the reply! 
did u mean this line? -`db.collection("itemImages").document().setData(["pic": //idk what path to specify so that it is displayed in the same document with the rest of the fields])`
if yes, any paths I tried to use to my SingleItem with all the `var`s -don't work.

Comment: Where are you first creating the document? At that point, you should have access to the ID, right? None of the code for posting to Firestore is actually shown here in the post...

Comment: @jnpdx sorry about that, it seemed to me that I added Firestore.
I edited the question.

Comment: You still aren't showing where you call `addItem`, so it's unclear. My suggestion: upload the file before calling addItem. Then, in `addItem`, store your page that you generated when you uploaded to Storage. Good luck!

Comment: @jnpdx can you take a look again? I added a block where I call this function.

Comment: Okay, but you aren't showing where `updateOrAddItem()` is called, so it's really no different. Can you try the suggestion I gave?

Comment: @jnpdx my fault. I added it, now its totally clear! If your solution regarding my code doesn't work, then I'll try what you suggested earlier. I promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your `path` in `uploadImage`. You just need to update your object with that path that you statically created.

```
// You make the path to the image here
let path = "itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
```

You can do this multiple ways, but you need something like

```
func uploadImage() {
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let picData: Data  = pickedImages[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
    let path = "itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
    let ref = storage.child(path)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
    let uploadTask = ref.putData(picData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (storageMetaData, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        } else {
            // Upload succeeded with the path you added
            // So set the pic variable to the path
            self.viewModel.singleItem.pic = path
            // Then update the item
            self.viewModel.updateOrAddItem()
        }
    })        
}
```

Comment: I know that I have already marked the answer as correct, as it is in fact, and a lot of time has already passed, but I still have questions regarding your answer, if it doesn’t make you difficult, I will be glad. 
This code creates two identical `documents`, one without the storage `path` in the `pic` field, and the other with `path` (thanks to your answer) what could be the problem?

Also I asked this in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128968/duplicated-document-in-collection-when-added-to-firestore (more detailed question)

Comment: @JohnSmith Ill answer your question on your other post