# Duplicated document in collection when added to Firestore

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, firebase-storage

There is a `handlerDoneTapped()` function, which is applied when the `Done` button is clicked, which saves data from the fields, including the image and `path` to it, into the Firestore.

```
    func handleDoneTapped() {
        self.viewModel.handleDoneTapped()
        self.uploadImage()      // For Storage and path to it         
        self.dismiss()
    }
```

Inside the `handleDoneTapped()` function, there is another `uploadImage()` function that uploads an image to `Storage` and saves the `path` to the `pic` parameter.

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NewItemView()

    func uploadImage() {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        let picData: Data = pickedImages[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
        let path = "itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
        let ref = storage.child(path)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        _ = ref.putData(picData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            } else {

                self.viewModel.singleitem.pic = path      // I specify the path to the pic parameter [singleitem - also from NewItemView()]
                self.viewModel.updateOrAddItem()        // I make changes through the function from NewItemView()
                
            }
        })
        }
```

`@ObservedObject var viewModel = NewItemView()` - refers us to Firestore parameters for saving data.

```
  class NewItemView: ObservableObject {

  @Published var singleitem: SingleItem

    init(singleitem: SingleItem = SingleItem(title: "", author: "", description: "", pic: "")) {
    self.singleitem = singleitem
    
      self.$singleitem
      .dropFirst()
      .sink { [weak self] singleitem in
        self?.modified = true
      }
      .store(in: &self.cancellables)
  }

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
  private func addItem(_ singleitem: SingleItem) {
    do {
        var addedItem = singleitem
        addedItem.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        _ = try db.collection("items").addDocument(from: addedItem)
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }

  private func updateItem(_ singleitem: SingleItem) {
    if let documentID = singleitem.id {
      do {
          try db.collection("items").document(documentID).setData(from: singleitem)
      }
      catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
  
  public func updateOrAddItem() {          // This func I call inside uploadImage() to update path for pic parameter
                                           // (bc without that pic: "" -is empty inside Firestore)
    
      if singleitem.id != nil {
      self.updateItem(self.singleitem)
    }
    else {
      addItem(singleitem)
    }
  }

 func handleDoneTapped() {         // This func I call when I tapped Done button to add or update item
    self.updateOrAddItem()
  }
```

and finally `SingleItem` struct with all `var`s:

```
struct SingleItem: Identifiable, FirestoreProtocol {
    @DocumentID var id : String?
    @ServerTimestamp var createdTime: Timestamp?
    var title : String
    var author : String
    var description : String
    var userId : String?
    var pic : String
}
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case author
    case description = ""
    case pic
  }
```

So, I understand that I call the `self.viewModel.updateOrAddItem()` function twice, but if I don't use this function inside `uploadImage()`, then the document is saved without the `pic` parameter, which contains the `path` to the image in Storage.
But when I'm using this function inside `uplaodImage()`, two identical documents are saved into the Firestore with the difference that one of them contains the `path` to the image in the `pic` field.

In general, I'm a little confused, I tried to change the parameters for entering data using these functions in order to filter out a duplicate document that does not contain the necessary information, but everything leads to the fact that the document is saved without a `pic` field (`path` inside is empty), or two, which one of them is needed, and the other is not.

Maybe someone will see where I'm making a mistake. Also I have provided only the necessary code that is relevant to the problem, part of the code, as well as brackets may be missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This ` @ObservedObject var viewModel = NewItemView()` has the potential to create new view model instances if the view is redrawn.  The view model should be injected from a superview or come from the environment.  Your `uploadImage` code also belongs in your view model or model.

Comment: have you tried using `@StateObject var viewModel = NewItemView()`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes, nothing changes.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your firebase console showing the two documents that are incorrect. I assume that if you have two, then they have different IDs, is that correct?

Comment: @ColdLogic Done! Documents id yes, but who added it (userId) same.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yea, so when you're calling `updateOrAddItem`, its never doing the update process, because `singleitem.id` is still nil. You should just need to make sure thats populated to make sure it updates properly

Comment: @ColdLogic Just ran your code in my project and it seems to work! I needed a little tweaking (little things), but everything works! Just one little problem with block here:

`print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
self.rateitem.id = ref!.documentID`

**Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type `StorageReference` Remove `!`
Value of type `StorageReference` has no member `documentID`**

Can't understand where did you get `documentID` from `ref`?

Thanks u so much for the help, u r a lifesaver!

Comment: @JohnSmith `documentID` should be a value on `DocumentReference` which is the return value from the `addDocument` call. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference.html#documentid

Comment: @ColdLogic so like I said I run your code and its works! until I tried to upload one more and its just replaced with previous document.
Problem with `self.rateitem.id = ref!.docimentID`
 I guess?
Because I run this code without this line to check.

Comment: @ColdLogic I tried everything possible, of course with the code that you fixed with `ref`,  still the same document is replaced by a new one.

Comment: @JohnSmith what is `rateitem`? I dont know which version of code you are using as there were 2 solutions in my post. Are you only calling `update`? Or are you still using `addDocument`?

Comment: @ColdLogic sorry for confusing, my bad.`rateitem` its same `singleItem`, I changed this name a long time ago in my code and accidentally used this name.
I'm using `class SingleItemService`, and I understood that the problem is.
In this line: `try items.document(itemId)` - where did you get the `itemId` parameter from?

Comment: @JohnSmith ah, it would just be `item.id`. In the version of `SingleItem` below, the `id` field is required, and has a default value that is created locally, instead of relying on Firebase to make it.

Comment: @ColdLogic now it works as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have given, it sounds like you're uploading your object twice. I can tell you will have some asynchronous problems with your code, so I am going to assume that is the problem, please respond with more information if this doesn't work.

In your `addItem` function, you never update your local object with the updates to `singleitem`.

```
private func addItem(_ singleitem: SingleItem) {
    do {
        var addedItem = singleitem
        addedItem.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        // Since you are adding the document to Firebase, you need to update
        //     your local object. This will give it the generated ID from Firebase
        let ref = try db.collection("items").addDocument(from: addedItem) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with ID: \(ref.documentID)")
                self.singleItem.id = ref.documentID
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
```

I am guessing if you were to put debug your `updateOrAddItem` function, `updateItem` is never called because an ID is never saved to `singleitem`

All of this should be highlighting the problems with your asynchronous code. You essentially have to make 3 asynchronous calls to just create your object. One to get an ID, a second to upload your image, and third to update your object with the locally generated path of the image.

This is more of an opinion from here on out, but you can just create all this information and reduce all of this web traffic like this:

```
struct SingleItem: Codable {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    
    var author : String?
    var createdTime: Date = Date()
    var description : String?
    var pic : String?
    var title : String?
    var userId : String?
}

class SingleItemService {
    private lazy var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private lazy var items = db.collection("items")

    func update(_ item: SingleItem) {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        else {
            print("Not logged in");
            return
        }

        item.userId = userId

        do {
            try items.document(item.id).setData(from: item, merge: true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then your class can change to this

```
class NewItemView: ObservableObject {

    @Published var singleItem: SingleItem

    private lazy var itemService = SingleItemService()

    init(initialItem: SingleItem = SingleItem()) {
        singleItem = initialItem

        // Rest of Init code
    }

    func handleDoneTapped() {
        itemService.update(singleItem)
    }
}
```

Upload image can then become:

```
func uploadImage() {
    let picData: Data = pickedImages[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
    let path = "itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"

    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let ref = storage.child(path)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        
    _ = ref.putData(
        picData,
        metadata: metadata,
        completion: { (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            } else {
                // Get the current item
                let item = self.viewModel.singleItem
                item.pic = path

                // Update it in Firebase
                let service = SingleItemService()
                service.update(item)

                // Update the view model with the new item
                self.viewModel.singleItem = item
            }
        }
    )
}
```